# php - how to insert a word only between two words in a string?

Tags: php, string

I want to add the string `xx` between words, assuming that neither `xx` nor `yy` already exists between those words. Examples:

1. `this house` -> `this xx house`
2. `this xx house` -> `this xx house`
3. `this yy house` -> `this yy house`
4. `this is my house` -> `this xx is xx my xx house`
5. `this yy is my house` -> `this yy is xx my xx house`
6. `xx xx` -> `xx xx xx`
7. `this is my house yy indeed` -> `this xx is xx my xx house yy indeed`

The idea is to insert the word `xx` by default BETWEEN TWO WORDS if there is neither another `xx` nor another `yy`. But, if in MIDDLE of two words there exists an `xx` or a `yy` do not add anything.

How do I write this function?

Comment: Have you tried something to achieve your goal?

Comment: explode on space, loop , a little tricky

Comment: I've tried some substring but nothing

Comment: Doesn't rule 6 contradict rule 2, or is opening a gap to interpretation?

Comment: No, since xx is still a word, so if I have xx xx I need to insert the xx inside both words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming up with an answer:

```
function my_function($string){

    $value = "";

    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
    $string = explode(" ", $string);

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($string); $i++ ){ //"for loop" here

        if( $i !== (sizeof($string) - 1) ){    //do not count the last element 

            if( strtolower($string[$i + 1]) !== "xx" && strtolower($string[$i + 1]) !== "yy" ){ //if next element is not an "and" then we should add it

                if( strtolower($string[$i]) !== "xx" && strtolower($string[$i]) !== "yy" ){ //if the actual element is not already an "AND"
                    array_splice($string, $i + 1, 0, "xx" );
                    $i = $i + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($string as $i){
        $value = $value . $i . " ";
    }
    return $value;
}
```

thanks for the answers

Answer (score -1):

Write the code to replace " xx " with "##@@%%xx%%@@##" and then replace every space with " xx " then replace every "##@@%%xx%%@@##" with " xx "

By collapsing the spaces with something you can expand later you can focus on new additions.

Then do the same for yy